# Странно работает функция C++

Tags: c++, функции

В программе пишутся координаты и длина линии. почему-то не работает х6 y3 длина 3

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int S = 10;
char MAP[S][S];

//выводит карту на экран
void display()
{
    system("cls");
    for (int i = 0; i < S; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < S; j++)
        {
            cout << MAP[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}
//закрашивает пиксель
void fillP(int x, int y)
{
    MAP[y - 1][x - 1] = '#';
}
//закрашивает несколько пикселей
void fillP(int x, int y, int counter)
{
    for (int i = x; i <= counter; i++)
    {
        MAP[y - 1][i - 1] = '#';
    }

}

int main()
{
    fillP(6, 3, 3);

    fillP(2,7,8);


    display();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так у вас в цикле условие странное/бессмысленное

```
for (int i = x; i <= counter; i++)
```

Как же это будет работать, если изначально `x` равно `6`, а `counter` равно `3`? Вы сравниваете *координату* с *количеством*. Это примерно как сравнивать километры с литрами.

Вы уж определитесь, как именно вы хотите реализовать этот цикл. Либо цикл реализуется в единицах *количества*

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
  MAP[y - 1][x + i - 1] = '#';
```

либо в единицах *координат*

```
for (int i = x; i < x + counter; i++)
  MAP[y - 1][i - 1] = '#';
```

А у вас получился какой-то бессмысленный "гибрид" из этих двух вариантов.